# Adding new object in array in existing array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, antd

I have a CRUD functionality in my react application using hooks and es6. 
I'm using AntDesign List Component as well. In my add function, after adding for the first time, it's expected that it's been added on the list.

[image]

But after creating another one, it's just replacing the existing array. It's not been added like index 1. It's always index 0.

[image]

Here's my code

```
const leaveTypeList = [];
const [isLeaveType, setLeaveType] = useState(leaveTypeList);

useEffect(() => {
  setLeaveType(leaveTypeList);
}, [setLeaveType]);

const payload = {
  leaveTag: values.leaveTag,
  leaveTagColor: values.leaveTagColor,
  hexCode: state.tagColor,
  dateCreated: formatLeaveTypeDate,
};

leaveTypeList.push(payload);
setLeaveType(leaveTypeList);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should push the new data by `isLeaveType.push(payload)`.

Also,

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setLeaveType(leaveTypeList);
}, [setLeaveType]);
```

makes no sense to me.
Since the `setLeaveType` is the setter for `isLeaveType`, there is no reason for the effect to depend on it.

Answer (score 2):

hey since you need to add a new item to array there is no need of the useEffect hook

```
const leaveTypeList = [];
const [isLeaveType, setLeaveType] = useState(leaveTypeList);

const payload = {
  leaveTag: values.leaveTag,
  leaveTagColor: values.leaveTagColor,
  hexCode: state.tagColor,
  dateCreated: formatLeaveTypeDate,
};

setLeaveType([...isLeaveType,payload]);
```

you can simple use setter to set new state updating the existing array by adding the new payload to it.

Comment: @AlyssaReyes Not just a good suggestion, this is actually the correct answer. You should not mutate state so the accepted answer shows a lack of knowledge about React. [Here](https://nl.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-forceupdate) is a reference.

Comment: @HMR Hello. I actually change my code that suggested here. But since Harry Chang first commented and tried his solution, it worked on my end. So I think I'm being fair with him accepting his answer :)